# AngularJS how to access json with special character? escaping charactor

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

however this json has special character ":" in the elements and I need to access them in html by using {{}} in angularJS, for example I need to retrieve "The Exes". 
[image]

I get data in one my controllers

```
<div>
    <div class="row cardContainer">
        <div class="cardHeader">{{data.feed.entry.im:name.label}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `{{ data.feed.entry["im:name"].label }}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in Javascript you can access to that kind of attributes using a different notation: square brackets

```
<div>
    <div class="row cardContainer">
        <div class="cardHeader">{{data.feed.entry['im:name'].label}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```